# Accessing native IOS functions from Instruments Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Can someone please help me with this?

I have an Objective C application that accesses contact book; builds a list of user name, email id and their picture; displays it on screen using a list.

I want to automate test of this functionality using Instruments. I want to retrieve the list of users from the Tableview on screen. This works. From this list, I also get the email id and the picture. What I want to do now is to be able to take this contact data and validate it against the Contact book. However, I do not see how I can call an Objective C function to do so from Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this, although we're trying to deicde on the best one. Candidates:

- A quasi-hidden text field that you insert into from UIAutomation and your app reads from, does stuff, and then writes back to (or writes to a different one). The con is that it seems UIA tries to be smart about hidden text fields. But I'm sure there's a way to make it less smart.
- A network server that runs on the host and communicates with a listener on the app to exchange data. Pain to setup, but guaranteed to work. We already have this channel because we use Nimbus and CSS/XML with runtime updates during development, so it's easier for us than most.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call Objective-C functions from the JavaScript within UI Automation. That JavaScript runtime is entirely sandboxed. The only way to communicate with the application is through the UIAElement scripting interface.

If you are looking for a testing tool that lets you call any arbitrary Objective-C object, you might want to look into [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF). It runs *inside* your app and is written in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I also had the same thoughts on the sandbox architecture but was hoping (against hope!) that the architecture was something like Robotium on Android which allows you to call native Android Java functions from within Robotium automation code. I will check with my team on whether we can use KIF - that may be a possibility if it does not require the AppUnderTest to be modified in any way. Thanks